# Domain mirrors my site using CloudFlare NS

Tags: cloudflare

I've noticed that a site that uses Cloudflare DNS is mirroring my website. I've tried blocking the IP in Apache, CSF/Iptables...no luck. I'm not familiar with Cloudflare but digging more I've found out that it actually masks the website real ip. 2hrs of digging later, I found a tool that brags to get me the real Ip but for this particular site, it says "no real ip was found".

Evidently, I've contacted Cloudflare but they keep spitting the same template over and over, "we aren't a hosting provider but a proxy" bullshit. Long story short, I don't know how to block this website for pointing its NS to my IP.

edit: I've changed the ip of the site to another one (I run a dedicated server and I have a few more). However, while propagating, the infringing site was giving some 404 errors, which made me happy. However, 2 hrs later, it seems to be working fine, even with the changed IP.

Comment: Please add your actual domain and the domain supposedly mirroring/proxying/pointing to your site. Otherwise no-one else can investigate this for you, and we already have good general answers to similar questions.

Comment: my site is: https://www.coinelitist.com and the infringing site is http://www.manukajar.com Sorry, I didn't post the actual sites thinking it may get flagged as advertising or something.

Comment: We encourage [posting the real information](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) whenever you can, because it makes solving the problem easier in many cases, and possible in others.

Comment: The other site does not seem to have a _current_ copy of your site. It seems to date back to August. Have they actually copied anything after that time?

Comment: Every time I post an article, it immediately appears on that site as well. The weird thing is that the site template, is an older version as you've noticed, but the article page is the actual new template.

Comment: I still cannot figure out the issue, made a bunch of Apache rules, with no effect. The Cloudflare IP doesn't seem to be blocked in any way.